# Get resolved type (and jsdoc tags) of variable initializer using TypeScript compiler API

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

Starting from the `ts.Node` for the initializer of `p.prop1` below, is there a simple way to get the resolved type info (including doc tags/comment) for `Props.prop1` using a type checker?

```
interface Props {
  /**
   * Doc comment
   * @tag
   */
  prop1: string;
}

const p: Props = { prop1: 'hello' };
//                 ^^^^^
```

I'm aware of APIs like `getTypeAtLocation`, `getDeclaredTypeOfSymbol`, `getApparentType`, and `getPropertyOfType`, but haven't been able to figure out how to combine them (or what other APIs might be needed) to do what I want. Calling `typeChecker.getSymbolAtLocation(node)` on the `prop1` initializer node returns a symbol which doesn't have the full type information.

(Ultimately what I want is the JSDoc tags, which once you have the right `ts.Symbol` can be acquired with `symbol.getJsDocTags()`.)

Answer (score 2):

**Getting type of `prop1` identifier in object literal expression**

To get the type, you can use `getTypeAtLocation` on the type checker:

```
// prop1 is a variable containing the ts.Node (ts.Identifier) of
// the node you highlighted in your question
const prop1Type = typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(prop1.name);

// outputs: string
console.log(typeChecker.typeToString(prop1Type));
```

**Getting its JS doc tags**

I'm honestly not sure what the correct way to get the JS doc tags are, but I've found it works to get the object literal expression's contextual type (I think that means it gets the definition type) then from there get the property of `prop1`:

```
const prop1Symbol = typeChecker.getSymbolAtLocation(prop1Symbol)!;
const propsType = typeChecker.getContextualType(prop1.parent)!;

// outputs the tag
console.log(propsType.getProperty(prop1Symbol.getName())!.getJsDocTags());
```

**Full Example**

```
import { createProjectSync, ts } from "@ts-morph/bootstrap";

// setup
const project = createProjectSync({ useInMemoryFileSystem: true });
const sourceFile = project.createSourceFile("file.ts", `
interface Props {
  /**
   * Doc comment
   * @tag
   */
  prop1: string;
}
const p: Props = { prop1: 'hello' };
`);
const typeChecker = project.createProgram().getTypeChecker();

// Get the prop1 identifier in the `p` variable declaration's initializer's
// object literal expression
const varStmt = sourceFile.statements.find(ts.isVariableStatement)!;
const varDecl = varStmt.declarationList.declarations[0];
const varDeclObjLit = varDecl.initializer as ts.ObjectLiteralExpression;
const prop1 = varDeclObjLit.properties[0] as ts.PropertyAssignment;

// outputs: string
const prop1Type = typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(prop1.name);
console.log(typeChecker.typeToString(prop1Type));

// outputs the js doc tag
const prop1Symbol = typeChecker.getSymbolAtLocation(prop1.name)!;
const propsType = typeChecker.getContextualType(prop1.parent)!;
console.log(propsType.getProperty(prop1Symbol.getName())!.getJsDocTags());
```